# Problem in persisting simple object in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following Model class:

```
package com.swaranga.model;

public final class Book
{
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String isbn;

    public Book(){}

    public Book(String title, String isbn)
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public final Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    private final void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public final String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }


    public final void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public final String getIsbn()
    {
        return isbn;
    }


    public final void setIsbn(String isbn)
    {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    //assume valid equals and hashcode
}
```

The have the following mapping file Book.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>

        <class name="com.swaranga.model.Book" table="book">
            <id name="id" type="long">
                <generator class="native"/>
            </id>

            <property name="title" column="title" type="string"/>

            <property name="isbn" column="isbn" type="string"/>
        </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

The following database schema:

```
    CREATE TABLE  `hibernatetest`.`book` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `isbn` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The following hibernate config file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>          
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateTest </property>

        <property name="connection.username"> root </property>

        <property name="connection.password"> latitude </property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>

        <property name="myeclipse.connection.profile">mysql</property>

        <mapping resource="com\swaranga\model\Book.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And finally the following code to persist a `Book` object:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File f = new File("hibernate.cfg.xml");     
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.configure(f).buildSessionFactory();     
        Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();       
        s.beginTransaction();       
        s.save(new Book("JDBC", "ISBN_!@#"));       
        s.flush();      
        s.disconnect();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following output in the console:

```
Hibernate: insert into book (title, isbn) values (?, ?)
```

But when I check my database, there are no entries.

Apologies for such a long question, but I felt necessary to supply all the details. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try editing the end of your main method to this:

```
Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();       
s.save(new Book("JDBC", "ISBN_!@#"));       
tx.commit();
s.flush();      
s.disconnect();
```

Comment: Got it. I had to say `s.getTransaction().commit();` after `s.save();`Now it works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is "auto" a valid generator class?

It is not listed on the O/R mapping part of the docs and from what it looks like you are doing you are not generating an ID in code or in the database:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html

I would look at native if you want to assign ids, or do an identity generator to let MySQL handle it.

Comment: Did you re try the program?
"could not interpret id generator strategy: auto"
suggests that it still thinks you are using auto.

Comment: Also, to use identity, you need to specify the id column to be auto-incrementing in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried id type "long"?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set the id of the database to be auto-increment. Try that. Should work.

Comment: I did that. Now there is a different problem. See edited question.